# how can i know what is the max values of volume in android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

```
AudioManager mgr=null
mgr = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100, 
   AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),0);`
```

Comment: its works but basically i want to get values from device i m new in android and making volume booster app so when ever the user decrease the volume it increase it